# IPhone: Uploading a new version of an app - is there an approval process?

Tags: iphone, app-store

When I upload a new version of my app to appstore does it go through the same approval process as the first time I uploaded the app?

Comment: Yes, you will have to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the same process, but you have to re-submit the app with a different version number. Usually the approve process is faster the fewer the changes you have made : i.e. for bugfixes will be faster than adding new functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a less involved process, but it still gets looked at.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to go through the process. I am not sure whether it will be the identical process. Anyway, there have been reports that the same app had been denied after some minor updates.